# Agrupar itens por um campo em arrays diferentes

Tags: php, array

```
 $resultado = $modelSga->getConsultaSga($ano, $mes, $unidade);

                foreach ($resultado as $res) {

                        $idServico = $res->id_serv;

                        $servico = array();
                        if($idServico != $idServicoAnterior) {
                            array_push($servico, $res->nm_serv);
                        echo($servico[0]);
                        }
                        echo "<br/>";

                }
```

O que estou tentando fazer é para cada `ID_SERV` diferente ele pegará o `nm_serv` e armazenará em um *array* agrupando. Isso será útil pois irei criar uma tabela para cada informação diferente. ex:

SETOR 
carro
carro
carro
carro

SETOR 
moto 
moto 
moto 
moto

SETOR 
.... 
.... 
....

[image: tabelas que devem sair]

Comment: Não entendi. Pode descrever um pouco melhor? Principalmente no título que não diz qual é o seu problema.

Comment: Pode esclarecer melhor o que você deseja? não entendi bolhufas...

Comment: Então, eu vou montar uma tabela de 5 colunas só que as informações serão dividas, ou seja, cada id_serv (que também é nm_serv) irá virar uma tabela, tipo imagem que postei.

Comment: o id_serv é o que acredito que usarei para dividir as tabelas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Provavelmente seja mais simples fazer a saida ficar numa sub-array:

```
$saida = array();
foreach ($resultado as $res) {
   //se o indice id_serv ainda nao estiver na $saida, adicionamos uma array vazia:
   if( !isset( $saida[$res->id_serv] ) ) {
      $saida[$res->id_serv] = array();
   }
   //acrescentamos o item na subarray desejada:
   array_push( $saida[$res->id_serv], $res->nm_serv );
}
```

Se quiser por vários campos no array de saída, basta fazer desta forma:

```
array_push( $saida[$res->id_serv], array(
   'Matricula'    => $res->matricula,
   'Nome'         => $res->nome,
   'Atendimentos' => $res->atendimentos
) );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/wdSy8F)**

Para usar como se fossem arrays separadas e montar uma tabela, basta fazer isso depois:

```
foreach( $saida as $grupo => $itens ) {
    echo "<h1>$grupo</h1>";
    foreach( $itens as $item ) {
       echo 'Matricula: '.$item['Matricula'];
       echo 'Nome: '     .$item['Nome'];
       ... etc ...
    }
}
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, e pelo jeito que você passou vou conseguir até mais facilmente fazer o que quero, infelizmente ainda me complico com arrays. Valeu.

Answer (score 2):

O problema principal do teu código é que você está limpando o *array* a cada *loop*.

```
foreach ($resultado as $res) {
   ...
   $servico = array();
```

Para esse tipo de lógica você deve declarar o *array* fora do *loop* e apenas incrementa-lo.

```
$servico = array();
foreach ($resultado as $res) {
   {...}
   array_push($servico, $res->nm_serv);
   {...}
}
```

**(Se eu entendi corretamente o problema...)**