# Usando Inner Join de forma correta e agregando resultados

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

No meu BD, tenho 4 tabelas: `Aluno`, `Ano`, `Matérias` e `Nota`. Elas estão montadas da seguinte maneira:

```
Tabela    :: Colunas
----------------------------------------------------------
Aluno     :: AlunoID     | AlunoNome    | AnoID
Ano       :: AnoID       | AnoNome
Materia   :: MateriaID   | MateriaNome  | AnoID
Nota      :: NotaID      | AlunoID      | MateriaID | Nota
```

Estou tentando usar um `inner join` para unir todos os dados:

```sql
Aluno a INNER JOIN      Ano b on ( a.AnoID   = b.AnoID   )
        INNER JOIN  Materia c on ( b.AnoID   = c.AnoID   )
        INNER JOIN     Nota d on ( a.AlunoID = d.AlunoID )
```

De fato, eu estou conseguindo unir os dados! Só que estou tendo um problema - 
na tabela `Aluno`, tenho dois registros. Quando uso o `echo` para exibir os alunos, os nomes se repetem a cada matéria e cada nota.

Fica algo parecido com isso:

```
Aluno1 Ano1 Materia1 Nota1
Aluno1 Ano1 Materia2 Nota1
Aluno1 Ano1 Materia1 Nota2
Aluno1 Ano1 Materia2 Nota2

Aluno2 Ano2 Materia3 Nota3
Aluno2 Ano2 Materia4 Nota4
Aluno2 Ano2 Materia3 Nota3
Aluno2 Ano2 Materia4 Nota4
```

Como pode ser visto no exemplo acima, o resultado da consulta repete o nome e matéria, e alterna a exibição do restante dos resultados!

Gostaria que o resultado ficasse algo mais ou menos assim:

```
Aluno1 Ano1 Materia1 => Nota1 / Materia2 => Nota2 
Aluno2 Ano2 Materia3 => Nota3 / Materia4 => Nota4
```

Como podem ver, o nome agora repete-se apenas uma vez e as outras informações referentes a esse nome são colocadas ao lado!

Sei que posso resolver esse "problema" aumentando o numero de colunas direto na tabela `aluno`, colocando várias colunas chamadas `notai`, tipo `nota1`, `nota2`, `nota3`, mas, dessa forma, ficarei muito limitado.

Minha dúvida então é:

> Como unir as tabelas de tal forma que os nomes não fiquem repetindo e as informações referentes ao aluno apareçam ao lado?

Gostaria de estabelecer a relação real, já que um aluno pertence a um ano específico, esse ano específico possui X quantidade de matérias e cada aluno de cada ano ganhou Y nota em X matéria.

Não estou conseguindo fazer isso, está ficando tudo embolado tal como nos exemplos acima.

Comment: essa é uma maneira, estou localizando outra: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38809/70

Comment: mais uma: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105060/70

Comment: Basicamente você cria uma variável `$nomeAnterior = ''`, e faz um `if( $campo['nome'] != $nomeAnterior) { mostra o nome, e guarda ele em $nomeanterior`, senão mostra só nota e matéria.

Comment: Acho que seu último join precisa de mais uma relação entre matéria e nota

Comment: @Bacco tem como você me ajudar com algumas duvidas? Daria pra iniciarmos uma discussão com base nessa pergunta?

Comment: @ivanveloso Você viu a minha resposta? Ela te ajudou?

Comment: @VictorStafusa em termos sim e em outros não! Acho que a parte crucial pro meu problema é projetar melhor a minha ideia! 
se tiver como conversamos melhor sobre isso! Seria de grande utilidade!

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro problema que vejo é que você esqueceu um detalhe no seu `INNER JOIN`:

```sql
INNER JOIN     Nota d on ( a.AlunoID = d.AlunoID )
```

Ou seja, as notas puxadas em cada tupla são aquelas que se relacionam com o aluno, **e apenas com o aluno, estando livre com relação às matérias**. Você se esquece de relacionar as notas com as matérias, de forma que o resultado trás notas junto com matérias que não têm relação entre si. Ou seja, ele acaba fazendo um produto cartesiano entre as disciplinas e as notas de um aluno.

O correto seria isso:

```sql
INNER JOIN     Nota d on ( a.AlunoID = d.AlunoID AND c.MateriaID = d.MateriaID)
```

Quanto a junção das várias matérias e notas, é algo que eu não recomendo fazer, pois acredito que só torna as coisas mais difíceis e acho que essa ideia parte de uma falha na interpretação do significado dos resultados. Entretanto, caso você queira insistir nisso, acho que a solução para o seu problema é usar o [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```sql
SELECT
    a.AlunoNome,
    b.AnoNome,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT(c.MateriaNome, ' => ', d.Nota)
        ORDER BY c.MateriaNome
        SEPARATOR ' / '
    ) AS Boletim
FROM Aluno a
INNER JOIN Ano b ON a.AnoID = b.AnoID
INNER JOIN Materia c ON b.AnoID = c.AnoID
INNER JOIN Nota d ON a.AlunoID = d.AlunoID AND c.MateriaID = d.MateriaID
GROUP BY a.AnoID, a.AlunoID;
```